# Ignore regex group

Tags: regex

I have a string like:

```
/* here is text */

here is text
```

My regexp: `(?!\/\*.+?\*\/).+?`

Result:

> /*** here is text */**
>
> **here is text**

How is it possible to ignore `/* here is text */` and get a string without `/* here is text */`?

Comment: Use replace facilities of your language to replace comments regex with empty strings

Comment: In what environment do you want to use that regex? For a somewhat specialized regex like that it would be helpful to know if you want to use that regex in vim, grep, pearl, whatever... Also for further clarification, is this what you want to do: you want to not match text in C-Style block comments?

Comment: A common approach is match and ignore. Match any comments in the first group, the rest in the second, then extract the second match group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They don't skip any text during a regex match, they just assert that a certain regex can't be matched at the current position.

In your case that means that [your regex will match every single character (one for each time you perform the match operation) after the initial `/`](http://regex101.com/r/eX9nX4). You don't want that.

Use the regex `\/\*.+?\*\/\s*` to match all comments; if comments may span multiple lines, you will need to set the `DOTALL` or `Singleline` flag of your regex engine. Then replace those matches with the empty string.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/gJ3lX4).